# Rolling Correlation of Multi-Column Panda

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, correlation

I am trying to calcualte and then visualize the rolling correlation between multiple columns in a 180 (3 in this example) days window.

My data is formatted like that (in the orginal file there are 12 columns plus the timestamp and thousands of rows):

```
import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Timestamp" : ['1993-11-01' ,'1993-11-02', '1993-11-03', '1993-11-04','1993-11-15'], "Austria" : [6.18 ,6.18, 6.17, 6.17, 6.40],"Belgium" : [7.05, 7.05, 7.2, 7.5, 7.6],"France" : [7.69, 7.61, 7.67, 7.91, 8.61]},index = [1, 2, 3,4,5])

Timestamp   Austria Belgium France
1   1993-11-01  6.18    7.05    7.69
2   1993-11-02  6.18    7.05    7.61
3   1993-11-03  6.17    7.20    7.67
4   1993-11-04  6.17    7.50    7.91
5   1993-11-15  6.40    7.60    8.61
```

I cant just use this formula, because I get a formatting error if I do because of the Timestamp column:

```
df.rolling(2).corr(df)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1993-11-01'
```

When I drop the Timestamp column I get a result of 1.0 for every cell, thats also not right and  additionally I lose the Timestamp which I will need for the visualization graph in the end.

```
df_drop = df.drop(columns=['Timestamp'])
df_drop.rolling(2).corr(df_drop)


Austria Belgium France
1   NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN 1.0
3   1.0 1.0 1.0
4   -inf1.0 1.0
5   1.0 1.0 1.0
```

Any experiences how to do the rolling correlation with multiple columns and a data index?

Comment: In finding a solution It would help to be able to reproduce the (failing) behavior on you platform. To this end you should supplement your question with more code and data to get a minimal (not) working example.

Comment: added it, hope now its possible to re-create

Comment: `df.set_index('Timestamp').rolling(3).corr()`  If you only have 2 observations it will always be 1 or -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on the [answer of Shreyans Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64825103/333403) I propose the following. It should work with an arbitrary number of columns:

```py
import itertools as it

# omit timestamp-col
cols = list(df.columns)[1:]
# -> ['Austria', 'Belgium', 'France']

col_pairs = list(it.combinations(cols, 2))
# -> [('Austria', 'Belgium'), ('Austria', 'France'), ('Belgium', 'France')]

res = pd.DataFrame()

for pair in col_pairs:
    # select the first three letters of each name of the pair
    corr_name = f"{pair[0][:3]}_{pair[1][:3]}_corr"
    res[corr_name] = df[list(pair)].\
                    rolling(min_periods=1, window=3).\
                    corr().iloc[0::2, -1].reset_index(drop=True)

print(str(res))
```

```
   Aus_Bel_corr  Aus_Fra_corr  Bel_Fra_corr
0           NaN           NaN           NaN
1           NaN           NaN           NaN
2     -1.000000     -0.277350      0.277350
3     -0.755929     -0.654654      0.989743
4      0.693375      0.969346      0.849167
```

The NaN-Values at the beginning result from the windowing.

**Update:** I uploaded a notebook with detailed explanations for what happens inside the loop.

https://github.com/cknoll/demo-material/blob/main/pandas/pandas_rolling_correlation_iloc.ipynb

Comment: @CSBossmann Does this solution resolve the issue with the non-feasible effort of manually creating al combinations of 12 columns?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you! Assuming I want to replace it with a time window of 260 days and 12 columns what would I have to change  ?

Comment: Would it be?

`for pair in col_pairs:

    corr_name = f"{pair[0][:12]}_{pair[1][:12]}_corr"

    res[corr_name] = df[list(pair)].\

                    rolling(min_periods=1, window=260).\

                    corr().iloc[0::2, -1].reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: From what I can see you only nee to change `window=260`. The number of columns should adapt automatically since `cols = list(df.columns)[1:]` gives you *all* column names but the first one (index 0). Anyway, I would suggest to have a look at the intermediate results by using interactive techniques like ipython, or jupyter notebook, or even print(...). Understanding the intermediate results is very helpful for adapting the solution to your needs.

Comment: @cknoll
Could you help me understand what is the iloc operation doing in this step:
    res[corr_name] = df[list(pair)].\
                    rolling(min_periods=1, window=3).\
                    corr().iloc[0::2, -1].reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: @asimo I uploaded a notebook with detailed explanations: https://github.com/cknoll/demo-material/blob/main/pandas/pandas_rolling_correlation_iloc.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

You can probably calculate pair-wise correlation like this, instead of going for all 3 at once.

Once you have the correlation, you can directly add them as your columns as well, preserving the timestamp.

````
df['Aus_Bel_corr'] = df[['Austria','Belgium']].rolling(min_periods = 1, window = 3).corr().iloc[0::2,-1].reset_index(drop = True)
df['Bel_Fin_corr'] = df[['Belgium','Finland']].rolling(min_periods = 1, window = 3).corr().iloc[0::2,-1].reset_index(drop = True)
df['Aus_Fin_corr'] = df[['Austria','Finland']].rolling(min_periods = 1, window = 3).corr().iloc[0::2,-1].reset_index(drop = True)```
````

Comment: thanks for the advice. I forgot to mention in my post that these are just snippets of my data. In total I have 12 columns and a few thousand rows. is there another way to not do 1 to the power of 12 calculations?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that there is an another way.

```py
df['Aus_Bel_corr'] = df['Austria']\
                       .rolling(min_periods = 1, window = 3)\
                       .corr(df['Belgium'])
```

For me, I think it is a little simple than the previous answer.